# Compare and filter multidimensional arrays against each other in java script?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have two multidimensional arrays. The first one holds lots of data like this:

```
var dataarray = [ ["AX005A", "Dust / Gas", "1D / 2G", "21", "Ex II 3D IP67"],
["AX007A", "Dust / Gas", "3D / 3G", "22 / 2", "Ex II 3D T60"],
["AX008A", "Dust / Gas", "3D / 3G", "21", "Ex II 3D T60"],
["AX014A", "Dust", "3D", "22", "Ex II 3D T60"],
["AY042A", "Dust", "3D", "20", "Ex II 3D IP65 T65"],
["AY046A", "Dust", "3D", "21", "Ex II 3D T65"]];
```

The second one holds searchterms like this:

```
var searchterms = [["1","Dust / Gas"],["3","21"]];
```

Now I want a result array that only contains the data where the dataarray matches both searchterms each one at the correct index given by seachterms[n][0]

For the seachterms given above the resultarray would be:

```
resultarray = [["AX005A", "Dust / Gas", "1D / 2G", "21", "Ex II 3D IP67"],
["AX008A", "Dust / Gas", "3D / 3G", "21", "Ex II 3D T60"]];
```

Since the number of searchterms isn't always the same it has to be a generic solution that works with 2 searchterms as it does with 4 or 5 searchterms.

I've tried nested "for loops" with various if conditions but I got lost at some point :(

I would be awesome if someone can help. 
Only framework I can use is jquery (if that helps at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first solution would be:

```
function find(haystack, needles) {
    var results = [];
    for(var i = haystack.length; i--;) {
        var matches = true;
        var item = haystack[i];
        for(var j = needles.length; j--; ) {
            var needle = needles[j];
            if(needle[1] !== item[needle[0]]) {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(matches) {
            results.push(item);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/dXLQb/) (*I think you search term must be `["3","21"]`, not `["4","21"]`*)

You could restructure your code though and use *objects* instead of arrays (does not change that much for the find function, but is easier to create). E.g. `searchterms` could be an object `{0: "Dust / Gas", 3: "21"}`, which would change the inner `for` loop to

```
for(var key in needles) {
   if(needles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       if(needles[key] !== item[key]) {
           matches = false;
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: you are right with the search term remark.
works like a charm :) thanks lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I had to put my code to, I had it NOT WORKING because of the input mistake in your question. http://jsfiddle.net/cwZz7/3/     see it here

```
var dataarray = [ ["AX005A", "Dust / Gas", "1D / 2G", "21", "Ex II 3D IP67"],
["AX007A", "Dust / Gas", "3D / 3G", "22 / 2", "Ex II 3D T60"],
["AX008A", "Dust / Gas", "3D / 3G", "21", "Ex II 3D T60"],
["AX014A", "Dust", "3D", "22", "Ex II 3D T60"],
["AY042A", "Dust", "3D", "20", "Ex II 3D IP65 T65"],
["AY046A", "Dust", "3D", "21", "Ex II 3D T65"]];

var searchterms = [["1","Dust / Gas"],["3","21"]];    
/*
resultarray = [["AX005A", "Dust / Gas", "1D / 2G", "21", "Ex II 3D IP67"],
["AX008A", "Dust / Gas", "3D / 3G", "21", "Ex II 3D T60"]];
*/


var resultArray = new Array();

for(i=0;i< dataarray.length; i++)
{
    var valid = true;
    for(j=0;j < searchterms.length;j++)
    {
          var index = parseInt(searchterms[j][0]);
          if(dataarray[i][index] != searchterms[j][1]){
                 valid = false;
                 break;
          }         

    }
    if(valid == true)
            resultArray.push(dataarray[i]);

}

// resultArray will have your result
```